# How to delete erroneous email address from Android autofill?

Tags: auto-fill

The autofill in my phone is showing some outdated addresses in the suggestions when I have to enter my email address in certain apps.
Is there any way to delete these suggestions?

One such place where these email suggestions can be seen is in Chrome's settings, where you create a new address for form autofill. Go to Settings, Addresses and more, Add, scroll to the bottom and click on the email field, and your email addresses should be shown.

Comment: Try tapping and holding the suggestionm, that works in some apps.

Comment: It was worth a shot, but no, that didn't do it.

Comment: Is it suggestion of the keyboard or the app itself? If it's keyboard's, the addresses might be from your contacts

Comment: The suggestions are coming from Android's OS-wide form autofill.

Comment: What Android version and phone do you have?

Comment: I'm on Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me, and I resolved it by removing the data from [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com).